# Creating a new Angular 8 project doesn't give me options

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular7, angular-schematics, angular8

I'm creating a new Angular 8 project and I was trying to set the style sheets to **SCSS** and create angular **routing** from the beginning of the project. I know I can do it manually, but it was pretty nice to have the menu of options in the command line.

```
ng new my-project --style=scss --routing
```

But in Angular 7 it was giving me the options to be selected in the command line. How can I add this back to my Angular 8 CLI?

When I run `ng v` I get the following:

```
Angular CLI: 8.0.1
Node: 10.16.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.800.1
@angular-devkit/core         8.0.1
@angular-devkit/schematics   8.0.1
@schematics/angular          8.0.1
@schematics/update           0.800.1
rxjs                         6.4.0
```

Created an Issue just in case it's an actual bug: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14640

Comment: I think is by design of CLI they want to get rid of the options in the cli but instead let user choose what config they want to put in angular project

Answer (score 1):

Try to uninstall the global CLI and try again? I tried this locally and is working as expected.

```
npm unistall @angular/cli -g
```

Then install angular-cli latest

```
npm i  @angular/cli -g
```

Comment: Thanks I tried that already and created a ticket in angular cli. They have fixed the issue making sure it always give you the options

Comment: Ok, that's great.